# Locally "forking" a git repo

Tags: git

We tend to repeat the same set up drill when building our Rails projects, and so I was thinking of just creating a stub app called "Starter app" which we would then use to build out future projects.

I want to take this Starter app and then basically replicate or "fork" the repo into a new independent repo that would retain all the history but have none of the remote or upstream dependencies.

Is this as simple as doing a local clone and then deleting the remotes?

```
$ git clone . ../new_app
$ cd ../new_app
$ git remote set-url origin git://new.github.url
```

or just copying the repo locally and removing remotes?

```
$ cp -r . ../new_app
$ cd ../new_app
$ git remote set-url origin git://new.github.url
```

Would both of the above do the same thing?

Comment: Not sure about cloning, but copying and adjusting remotes should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either process should work for what you are looking for.

As for whether they are the same thing, they are very similar but copying (`cp -r`) will result in keeping the current branch setting whereas cloning (`git clone`) will put you back on the HEAD branch.

Cloning will still fetch other branches and you can still use `git checkout` to switch back on to a branch.

This probably won't matter much considering its likely there will only be one branch on a template repo anyway.

Comment: Great point about the branch settings- not that it matters much here but helps clarify- thanks!